# Get values from a DataGridView Column, empty row at the end c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am working with an application that allows me to add some rows to my **DataGridView**:

[image]

As you can see, the last row is empty, this is to allow adding more rows.
Ok, the problem arises when I try to get all the values ​​in the "Codigo" column:

- (DB)335T1613
- (DB)335T1642
- (DB)335T1644

The last row is empty, so there is no value and I get the following error:

> the new unconfirmed row cannot be deleted

This is my **code** where I am trying just to get these values:

```
private void buttonAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        /*if (dataGridViewTennetPaint.Rows(dataGridViewTennetPaint.Rows.Count - 1).IsNewRow)
        {
               dataGridViewTennetPaint.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridViewTennetPaint.Rows.Count - 1);
    }*/
        dataGridViewTennetPaint.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridViewTennetPaint.Rows.Count - 1);
        string data = string.Empty;
        int indexOfYourColumn = 0;
        int cont = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewTennetPaint.Rows)
        {
            //if (!row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Equals(null) || row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn] != null || row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value.ToString() != "" || row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value.ToString().Equals("") || row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Equals("") || row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value.ToString() != "")
            if (row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value != System.DBNull.Value)
            {
                data = row.Cells[indexOfYourColumn].Value.ToString();
                cont++;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Data contiene ... " + data + " cont: " + cont);
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Which line in the code gives the error?

Comment: If you allow users to “add” rows, then the grids `AllowUserToAddRows` property is set to `true`. With this property set to `true`, you can NOT remove the “last” NEW row. Fortunately, each row has a boolean property called `IsNewRow`. Therefore, in the `foreach` loop through the grid’s rows… add a check for this “new row” …  `if (!row.IsNewRow) { ... };`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove last line from DataGrid it self as Its no longer to use.

please set CanUserAddRows to false.

> CanUserAddRows="False"

**Batter to use** BindingList binding to DataGrid & Get all rows from TableView.